# Implementing ISCrollInfo for WPFExtension's ZoomControl. Calculating Offsets

Tags: c#, wpf, zooming, contentcontrol

I'm trying to implement `IScrollInfo` for [WPFExtensions](http://wpfextensions.codeplex.com/)' `ZoomControl` in order to be able to use this control in combination with `ScrollViewer`. However I'm having difficulty understanding how to correctly calculate `HorizontalOffset` and `VerticalOffset` properties and where I need to update them .At first I suspected it was TranslateX and TranslateY but  that only gives you the offset relative to the position of the content from the last time the `Zoom` property changed and not the global offset of the viewport.

1. This seems like a very common need for users of ZoomControl. Has this effort been done before?
2. WPFExtensions seems to be very poorly documented and not very
   self-explanatory, is there a good source of information to better
   understand how ZoomControl works?

EDIT: I've been using [this control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85603/A-WPF-custom-control-for-zooming-and-panning) as a reference in my efforts as it implements `IScrollInfo`. However the 2 controls have different approaches to invalidate the view and update data so it didn't get me very far. I prefer using WPFExtension's control since it is simpler to use, has better animation and seems to be more widely accepted.